# Facebook Developer Toolkit - ExtendedPermissons

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am trying to use the Facebook Developer Toolkit (http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) to publish user messages from my ASP.NET application.

My question is, how do I get permission to publish a message to a user's Facebook stream? The examples on MSDN are incorrect (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee702803.aspx)). They reference a class called NewEventGrantPermission which does not seem to exist. Can someone tell me how to prompt a user for an extended permission in my ASP.NET application?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with the following JavaScript:

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream");
```

Answer (score 1):

I was reading [that article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee702803.aspx) and it seems to me that the `NewEventGrantPermission` class you are referring to is actually a hyperlink control (on an aspx page?  Which is odd because the only page is `Default.aspx`).

There are 2 reasons I think this:

Note: the hyperlink control's Target should be set (in markup) as `"_blank"` to pop the `NavigateUrl` in a new window.

and this image:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ee702803.image5%28en-us,MSDN.10%29.gif

So if `NewEventGrantPermission` is the name of the hyperlink then it would make sense that is doesn't exist (Because the article never instructs us to do so!!).

The first half of the article is very straightforward, but once it starts mentioning the code behind its as if it was copied and pasted from a completely different article.
This might be one of the most vague/ incomplete articles I have ever read from the msdn site!!